# How can I get Chrome to resize this div when the padding changes?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

**Update**: added css transitions on fiddles to make it clearer

When the padding is removed from this div via javascript, Chrome doesn't resize the content to fit (i.e., the red div doesn't cover the yellow, it stays the same size):
http://jsfiddle.net/XDchs/4/

Likewise, if padding is added, the content is pushed outside of the div:
http://jsfiddle.net/XDchs/3/

Firefox resizes as I'd expect. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="content">blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
  background-color:blue;
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#inner {
  padding-left:100px;
  margin:2px;
  background-color:yellow;
  -webkit-transition:padding-left 2s;
  -moz-transition:padding-left 2s;
}
#inner.no-padding {
  padding-left:0;
} 
#content {
  background-color:red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inner").addClass("no-padding");
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Alex It is perfectly clear. Try setting the no-padding style on and off. Chrome appears to behave incorrectly. Good question. +1

Comment: When I comment out the Javascript on jsFiddle and run the script again, it does exactly what it's supposed to do on Chrome 24. Same behaviour on Firefox 17.

Comment: @Alex The problem is that the yellow div initially has a padding, and when it's removed by adding a class via javascript, the red div doesn't resize (in Chrome). In the second example it has no padding and padding is added via javascript, and again the red div doesn't resize. Commenting out the javascript defeats the purpose.

Comment: @DavidMinor I meant that when I run it with the Javascript, there's no left padding, and if I comment it out, there is left padding just like it's supposed to be according to the CSS.

Comment: @Alex The left padding *is* going away. That isn't the issue. The red div should resize to cover the yellow. In the second example when padding is added it again doesn't resize and extends past its parent div.

Comment: @DavidMinor In any case, you should read the documentation on the box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html . Browsers like Chrome make their best attempt to follow the stipulations outlined in that model.

Comment: @Alex I'm familiar with the box model. Chrome renders the content differently if the 'no-padding' class is added later via javascript than if it is in the HTML source to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by setting the content's width to 100% via javascript after adding the CSS class: http://jsfiddle.net/XDchs/6/

```
$("#content").width("100%");
```

I couldn't find a  CSS solution that completely worked.

Also, I filed this as a Chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171060

Comment: your solution would perform better if you just gave the `.no-padding` class the `width: 100%`. additionally you could use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: I mentioned on the other answer that this doesn't work because of the box model - the total width becomes 100% plus the margin, so the blue on the right gets covered up. If you meant something else, could you show it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why Chrome appears to behave incorrectly, but you can work around with resetting the width:

```
#inner.no-padding {
    padding-left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's close but the right margin gets covered up (due to the box model I assume). Interestingly if I get rid of the margin the workaround no longer works.